# Uso de flex em sub-items com elementos pais diferentes

Tags: css, flexbox

[image: Exemplo do flexbox usado]

Estou usando o flex para alinhar os items todos igualmente, porém, os sub-items de cada um deles não se alinham igualmente, usei o stretch para que se alinhassem e ganhassem o tamanho de acordo com o maior, porém não sei como faço para que os elementos de dentro dos items principais façam o mesmo entre si somente, gostaría de saber se há alguma forma, e como fazê-la, de forma detalhada para que eu entenda o que fazer ao invés de só copiar e colar código sem saber como funciona.

*Já pesquisei sobre o flex em vários sites, mesmo assim não sei como fazer isso.

Comment: complicado responder algo sem nem saber como está o código.

Comment: esse ai é só uma ilustração, quero saber como faço para que os sub-items, sigam o flex apenas deles, e não do pai, mesmo com pais diferentes, a ideia é só pra um código base com descrição, de nada adianta um código pronto.

Comment: O que você já tentou fazer? tem código?

Comment: ainda não, mas queria um norte para poder fazer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tentei reproduzir sua necessidade somente com div's e flex para fazer um código bem enxuto e fácil de entender. Tem um site muito bom para para entender melhor como funciona o flex: [Flexy Boxes](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="panel-team">

        <div class="panel-player">
            <div class="panel-foto">
                <img src="https://nerdsnewsbr.files.wordpress.com/2014/02/8c216-superman-facebook-image.jpeg" class="tamanho-foto" />
            </div>
            <div class="panel-descricao">
                <h3>Superman</h3>
                Info 1<br />
                Info 2
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-player">
            <div class="panel-foto">
                <img src="https://nerdsnewsbr.files.wordpress.com/2014/02/abfaa-batman_avatar-e1263852269689.jpg" class="tamanho-foto" />
            </div>
            <div class="panel-descricao">
                <h3>Batman</h3>
                Info 1<br />
                Info 2<br />
                Info 3<br />
                Info 4<br />
                Info 5
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-player">
            <div class="panel-foto">
                <img src="https://nerdsnewsbr.files.wordpress.com/2014/02/e9ed1-facebook-art-no-photo-image-batman-mickey-mouse-spock-elvis-rick-roll4.jpg" class="tamanho-foto" />
            </div>
            <div class="panel-descricao">
                <h3>Spock</h3>
                Info 1
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <style>
        .panel-team {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        .panel-player {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            margin: 10px;
        }
        .panel-foto {
            padding-bottom: 7px;
            flex: 0 1 auto;
            align-self: stretch;
        }
        .panel-descricao {
            color: white;
            background-color: black;
            padding: 10px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content:center;
            align-items: center;
            flex: 1 1 auto; 
        }
        .tamanho-foto {
            height: 319px;
        }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```